# Esfera de unity 3d no se mueve para ningun lado

Tags: c#, unity3d

Hola quiero que la esfera se mueva para la derecha y para la izquierda pero no se mueve. Este es mi codigo si alguien me pudiese ayudar se lo agradeceria.

```
using System.Collections;
```

using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class moveorb : MonoBehaviour {

```
public KeyCode moveL;
public KeyCode moveR;

public float horizVel = 0;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().velocity = new Vector3(horizVel, 0, 4);

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(moveL))
    {
        horizVel = -2;
        StartCoroutine (StopSlide ());
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(moveR))
    {
        horizVel = 2;
        StartCoroutine (StopSlide ());
    }
}

IEnumerator StopSlide()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (.5f);
    horizVel = 0;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Sucede que no definiste los KeyCodes, si no los tenés definidos no podés saber si se toco un input NULL

```
public KeyCode moveL; //KeyCode debe ser una tecla que quieras para ir a la izquierda
public KeyCode moveR; //KeyCode debe ser una tecla con la que quieras ir a la derecha
```

Si añadimos valores a los KeyCodes quedaría así:

```
public KeyCode moveL = KeyCode.L;
public KeyCode moveR = KeyCode.R;
```

Esto haría que cuando toquemos L la esfera vaya para la izquierda, y que cuando toquemos R vaya hacia la derecha.

Comment: Gracias por contestar pero si te fijas bien estaban definidos sabrias otra cosa que pudiese ser ??. Gracias

Comment: Me referia a que no les diste un valor, ahi te escribo un ejemplo.

Comment: Edité el mensaje, miralo, ahora al tocar la R va a ir a la Derecha y al tocar la L va a ir a la izquierda